# Passing secondary data to my second callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I want to use the variable intermediateData in my second callback but I don't know how to pass it there in my current situation. Anybody know how to do this?

````
   const unsubscribe = firebase
     .locations()
     .once('value')
     .then(async snapshot => {
       const promises = []
       const intermediateData = snapshot.val()

       snapshot.forEach(element => {
         promises.push(firebase.user(element.key).once('value'))
       })

       return Promise.all(promises)
     })
     .then(snapshots => {
       const userInformation = []

       snapshots.forEach(userSnapshot => {
         if (userSnapshot.exists()) {
           userInformation.push({
             userId: 1,
             name: userSnapshot.val().username
           })
         }
       })
     })

   return () => unsubscribe
 }, [firebase, setSnackbarState, userId]) ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could return an object that contains the `Promise.all` results and `intermediateData`

```
const unsubscribe = firebase
  .locations()
  .once('value')
  .then(async snapshot => {
      const promises = []
      const intermediateData = snapshot.val()

      snapshot.forEach(element => {
        promises.push(firebase.user(element.key).once('value'))
      })

      return Promise.all(promises).then(snapshots => ({snapshots, intermediateData})
                                                      // ^^ return object
      })
    .then(({snapshots, intermediateData}) => {
           // ^^^ destructure returned object
      const userInformation = []

      snapshots.forEach(userSnapshot => {
        if (userSnapshot.exists()) {
          userInformation.push({
            userId: 1,
            name: userSnapshot.val().username
          })
        }
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Place it in the outer closure:

```
let intermediateData;
const unsubscribe = firebase
 .locations()
 .once('value')
 .then(async snapshot => {
   const promises = []
   intermediateData = snapshot.val()

   snapshot.forEach(element => {
     promises.push(firebase.user(element.key).once('value'))
   })

   return Promise.all(promises)
 })
 .then(snapshots => {
   //
   // Now you can access intermediateData here
   //
   // ...
 })
```

Comment: This works! I preferred the other answers since it seemed better to me to do it like that. Thank you for your help though!